# Why do the ContentViews of my UITableViewCell in my UITableView overlaps?

Tags: uitableview

My problem is that the ContentViews in my `UITableView` overlaps when I set the height of my `UITableViewCell` smaller than the frame of my ContentView. I already tried to add a subview to the `UITableViewCell` itself, but it still overlaps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by applying `cell.clipsToBounds = YES` on each `UITableViewCell`. Thanks anyway!